# How to convert a grade in Italian scale to the UK grading scale?

Tags: united-kingdom, grades, italy

I got a grade as 99/110 during my Bachelor degree in Italy. What would be the conversion to the UK grading scale?

Comment: There's no standard equivalent, but ask your university for the _diploma supplement_ which helps other universities make the conversion. See also the possible duplicate question here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38917/20058 In particular, see the last part of my answer there (the Edit III).

Answer (score 2):

there are resources online that do some approximate conversion like [Scholaro](https://www.scholaro.com/gpa-calculator/Italy). You will have to use your exam grades (look on your diploma supplement) for your GPA, not the final grade. I'm Italian too and used similar services myself when I was looking for Master's programs in the US. To access the selected program you then typically need a certified translation if the official language of the school differs from your degree, i.e., Italian diploma English school. Depending on the school, they might also require you to show a fourth year of university education, e.g. `Master di primo livello`, as US and UK programs often follow the 4-year format. But this is not a general rule, but it happened to me.

As a side-note, if you graduated from Marconi University in Rome, you can ask for a US-diploma free of charge at graduation, or 200Eur (I think) after that. Marconi is a special case as it has an International branch in Washington which is approved by the US department of education.

Hope it helps :)